# Amazon Alexa to Raspberry Pi Communication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, raspberry-pi, aws-iot

I am trying to use an Amazon alexa to modify/run a script on my Raspberry Pi. I currently have a custom alexa skill that runs an Amazon lambda function and sends the message to a queue. I then have the raspberry pi constantly looking for updates in the queue.

However, I am looking at a better way to do this. Is it impossible to register my raspberry pi as an IoT device and communicate that way? I am open to any suggestions, let me know if you have any ideas as I am very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually setup your [Raspberry Pi with SSM Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/manage-raspberry-pi-devices-using-aws-systems-manager/) allowing commands to be run from within AWS onto your Raspberry Pi.

If you set this up on your Pi, your Lambda can then run the [send-command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html) which would allow the Lambda to directly send a list of commands to run (such as triggering the execution of script).

An example of calling this from within [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) is below

```
client = boto3.client('ssm')

response = client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=[
        'i-123456', #Replace this with your remote instance ID
    ],
    DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript',
    Parameters={
        'commands': [
            'python3 /home/ec2-user/script.py',
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I finally had the time to try this out but the setup link is very hard to follow. Do you know of any other resources to set up the Raspberry Pi to connect with SSM Manager?

Comment: The general install instructions are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-managedinstances.html. If you through each step it should be fairly easy. Unfortunately this is the only other link I have :)

Comment: I tried to run a pm2 process to start a .sh file but it didn't start on my pi. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using any relative commands? Everything should be absolute. It also worth noting by default it runs as a user named `ssm-agent` I believe :)

Comment: I get this error in my ssm command history.
----------ERROR-------
[PM2][Initialization] Environment variable HOME (Linux) or HOMEPATH (Windows) are not set!
[PM2][Initialization] Defaulting to /etc/.pm2

Comment: I believe this is because the user `ssm-agent` does not have a $HOME environment variable set. In fact it does not load with a bash profile. You can either export a value for this as a previous command in the `send_command` function or alternatively you can run `sudo su $USERNAME` to have the SSM session become another user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219381/discussion-between-mefew-and-chris-williams).